# In WordPress how to add post to custom pages:

Tags: wordpress, post, custom-pages

I am new to WordPress.

suppose i have made pages as follows
home,  news, about us

now if i want to create post for news page only 
news1, 
news2

then posting new post how could i set this settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create [page templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates).

Create one for all your pages.

Then, change the template of the page of news to the news template.

In that PHP file now you can do whatever.

For example, for *news.php*

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: My Custom Page
*/
//Here comes your PHP code, where create a $WP_Query(); and loop troough on that.
```